# Volume creation

Tags: matlab, volume

I have a database as such:

- `d(:,1)` = longitude
- `d(:,2)` = latitude
- `d(:,3)` = depth
- `d(:,4)` = toxic metal concentration.

The data is irregularly spaced, and as you can see, all data are vector data. Could you please tell me how to make a `volume` where   all the metal concentrations are plotted as color (so that easily identifiable where it is high or low) while longitude, latitude, and depth would be in the x-axis, y-axis, and z-axis respectively?

I know I have to make my `d(:,4)` = volume data (3D matrix which must correspond to lat, long and depth data). But I’m unsure how to create that 3D array...

Answer (score 1):

Try `scatter3(X,Y,Z,S,C)` (see [doc](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/scatter3.html))

X,Y,Z is self-explanatory. S is size of markers, and C the color; you can vary either according to your data.

Please, give it a try, and update your question if you encounter difficulties.

---

Update 1: Thanks to your comments I think that you want to **interpolate the data on a regular grid, and slice the data.**

```
% create a regularly spaced mesh between the exterma of the dataset
xx = linspace(min(d(:,1)),min(d(:,1)),100);
yy = linspace(min(d(:,2)),min(d(:,2)),100);
zz = linspace(min(d(:,3)),min(d(:,3)),100);

[xi,yi,zi] = meshgrid(xx, yy, zz);

% interpolate the data in the regular space
vi = interp3(d(:,1), d(:,2), d(:,3), d(:,4), xi, yi, zi, 'spline');

% choose the slice planes
xslice = [-10 10]; yslice = 0; zslice = [-100, -50, -10];

% display the sliced interpolated data
slice(xi,yi,zi,vi,xslice,yslice,zslice);
```

Look up the functions in the help (you may need to tune up the parameters).

But next time: try something yourself and post your attempt. It's much easier to help, plus you'll learn more.

Comment: Hi David, Thanks. If x, y, and z are lat, long, and depth respectively, with S=size and C=color, the 4th dimension is still missing (i.e. concentration of metal which I want to show with different color). However, the problem can be resolved by writing the command as: scatter3(x(:),y(:),z(:),[],metal(:)). But what I really want to do is to make isosurface of metal conc. which requires making a volume of 'metal' in the first place as shown here: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/slice.html. Please find a small portion of my database here: http://www.mediafire.com/view/?89kuz9e3yfrh92f

Comment: (Who's David?) Also It seems that you've found the solution to your problem yourself.

Comment: Hi Hugues, I'm not done ... I still don't know how to make a volume and thereafter slices out of it from a non-uniformly distributed data. It is nauseating when people just make beautiful colored graphs/animations from uniformly distributed random variables and functions which are of no scientific value at all :(

Comment: I updated my answer with linspace. meshgrid, interp3 and slice solution.

Comment: Volume creation doesn't work for non-uniform data with "interp". I tried it before and failed!